# CPU vs. Duration in SQL Server Profiler

Tags: sql, cpu, profiler, trace, duration

On [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173882(v=sql.80).aspx) article, I am reading that:

| Data column | Column Number | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Duration** | 13 | Amount of time (in milliseconds) taken by the event. |
| **CPU** | 18 | Amount of CPU time (in milliseconds) used by the event. |

I am troubleshooting a query that's using

- **CPU:** `2,650 ms`
- **Duration:** `733 ms`

Shouldn't these numbers be somewhat closer together?  How can the query use more CPU time than the entire duration of the event?

Thanks

Comment: You need to learn how operating systems work, in terms of providing time slices for different processes.  Here is a place to begin:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)#Time_slice.  Note:  in a multi-processor environment (or hyperthreaded environment), you need to take the number of processors/threads into account.

Comment: Check the execution plan. Looks like you have an paralell query there and that could explain why CPU time is longer than duration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is most likely happenings is that your SQL server is splitting your SELECT statement up to run on multiple threads on your Multi-core CPU. Judging by the times returned, I would venture to guess you have a Quad-Core CPU in your server.

For instance: If CPU1, Cpu2, and CPU3 all take 750ms and CPU4 takes 400ms, then you would have a combined total of 2650ms, but an overall duration of only 750ms.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; it makes total sense I don't know why that never occurred to me before.